# How do I send data to logstack from NodeJS with custom parameters?

Tags: node.js, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm currently using logstash-client:

```
const Logstash = require('logstash-client');     
const logstash = new Logstash({
  type: 'udp',
  host: 'server.com',
  port: 50000
});

logstash.send({"execution":"successful","sourceInfo":"[not set]"/*, ... */});
```

But as a result, in Kibana, all logs sent by the code above are grouped under the "message" parameter:

[image]

**How do make it so that the parameters I send (execution, sourceInfo etc) are on the same level as @timestamp, @version, _id etc?**

Maybe there is a different library that allows sending such requests?

The reason I need this is that I want to make search queries like `sourceInfo: "[not set]" AND execution: "successful"`, but it doesn't seem possible when these parameters are inside the message.